# Can't publish image from memory to Facebook using OpenGraph

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am unable to publish an image taken from a camera or from local storage in an Open Graph story.

Here is the code

```
OpenGraphObject exercise = OpenGraphObject.Factory
            .createForPost("my-app-share:exercise");
exercise.setProperty("title", "Title");
exercise.setProperty("description", "description");

OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory
        .create(OpenGraphAction.class);
action.setProperty("exercise", exercise);

List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

Bitmap image = decodeBitmapFromFilepath(imgPath);

images.add(image);

FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(
        getActivity(), action, "my-app-share:use", "exercise")
        .setImageAttachmentsForObject("exercise", images, true)
        .build();
ExerciseActivity.getUiHelper().trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

The thing is when I don't include

```
.setImageAttachmentsForObject("exercise", images, true)
```

everything works fine, FB opens and the story is presented as intended.

As soon as I ad the above line, I get a FacebookError in my LogCat with no explanation

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.

This is not included in the documentation by Facebook. in the Android versions above 4.1.2 the error occurs because there is a line missing in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file when declaring the content provider for Facebook.

I just added

```
android:exported="true"
```

In case anybody runs into the same problem.